# FindControlRecursive block at 3 layer of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

my problem is i have an basic findcontrolrecursive

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(this Control root, string id)
    {
        if (root.ID == id)
            return root;
        foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
        {
            Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
            if (t != null)
            {
                return t;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

function who work for my first 2 layer of gridview but at the layer 3 it block at the first case.

**I need to use "GridViewRowEventArgs e" like with Project_Details (in the exemple).**

Main gridview name is GridView, 
first layer gridview is Project_Details and 
second Layer gridview name is Demande_Ponctuelle

```
    GridView Project_Details = e.Row.FindControlRecursive("Project_Details") as GridView;  //find the gridview tier2


    GridView Demande_Ponctuelle = Gridview.FindControlRecursive("Demande_Ponctuelle") as GridView; //Find the gridview tier3
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get a reference to the child GridView, then use FindControl to get the Button inside it:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdSubClaimOuter.Rows) 
{
if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
{
    GridView gvChild = (GridView) row.FindControl("Demande_Ponctuelle");
    // Then do the same method for Button control column 
    if (gvChild != null)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvChild .Rows) 
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
            {
                Button btn = (Button ) row.FindControl("buttonID");
                if (btn != null )
                {
                    // do your work
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```